# Get Path form camera intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android-widget

Hi I am using camera intent like following...

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, (new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")));
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
```

now I don't know how to get image path that is currently clicked be camera in `onActivityResult()` method Please if any one know Help me...

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) 
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"camera cancelled", 10000);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }
    if ((requestCode == CustomerRequestActivity.TAKE_IMAGE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK))
    {
        // mode = MODE_VIEWER;
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null,null, null);
        int column_index_data = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        //THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT!
        String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
        Bitmap bm;
        Log.v("/////////////", "///////");
        Log.v("\n\n\n\n", capturedImageFilePath);
        Log.v("///////////", "///////////");
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(capturedImageFilePath);
        capturedImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can show your captured image in image view of your activity.